# Implement session in yii and extjs

Tags: php, extjs, yii

I am implementing `login` and `logout` functionality in `Yii` and `Ext JS`. So far I guess I have done that. But I want to maintain a session too so that when a user refresh the `ExtJS` page I want to stay on a current page if a user is still logged in and if the time passed user will logged out again.

*Note: 
I am using ajax request for login and logout*

I tried reading articles but didn't figure out how to do it

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/12124-how-to-implement-session-timeout/

I am new to yii so can anyone suggest me a roadway how to implement this functionality.

So far I have enable it in a config.php file

```
'session' => array (
    'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'sessionTableName' => 'sessions',
),
```

Answer (score 3):

In Yii "remeber me" functionality is implemented via cookies that are OK with extjs as well. So when logging in you should do something like the following:

```
$identity = new UserIdentity($this->username, $this->password);
if ($identity->authenticate() && $identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
    $duration = 3600*24*30; // 30 days
    Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration); // <----- here!
}
```

Most probably you already using `Yii::app()->user->login` somewhere so find it and add second argument.

Comment: i have already done this , what about the session time out when duration is of 60 min i.e. one hour , if i fire an ajax request after one hour i am still able to fetch the data even if m not logged in

Comment: bounty is given but answer wasn't this that i was looking for i mean it doesnt solve my issue at all

Comment: What's the exact problem you still have?

Answer (score 2):

I implemeted a custom login in Yii and the only thing I've to do is to "tell" to the App that someone is logged.

```
        $identity = new UserIdentity("login","pwd");
        // Check auth...
        // ...
        // if logging successful :
        Yii::app()->user->login($identity,3600);
```